# Functional tests on codeception do not work

Tags: php, codeception

I have the following code:

```
class FirstCest
{
    public function _before(FunctionalTester $I)
    {
    }

    public function _after(FunctionalTester $I)
    {
    }

    public function tryToTest(FunctionalTester $I)
    {               
        $I->amOnPage('/about');
    }
}
```

This is my config:

```
actor: FunctionalTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - \Helper\Functional
error_level: "E_ALL"
```

When I try to run: `tests/functional/FirstCest.php:tryToTest` I get:

> [RuntimeException] Call to undefined method
>   FunctionalTester::amOnPage

Comment: `var_dump($I); var_dump(get_class_methods(get_class($I))); exit;` What does that give you?

Comment: displays an object that is too large,
  the console is losing the beginning

array(12) {
  [0]=>
  string(11) "__construct"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "wantToTest"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "wantTo"
  [3]=>
  string(6) "__call"
  [4]=>
  string(7) "execute"
  [5]=>
  string(8) "expectTo"
  [6]=>
  string(6) "expect"
  [7]=>
  string(9) "amGoingTo"
  [8]=>
  string(2) "am"
  [9]=>
  string(13) "lookForwardTo"
  [10]=>
  string(7) "comment"
  [11]=>
  string(10) "haveFriend"
}

Comment: get rid of the first var dump then and just dump the methods $I has

Comment: I understood what the problem is, functional testing requires the use of the framework, I use phpixie in codeception for it there is no module

Answer (score 3):

Write your own module or use PhpBrowser. 
I see that you already started work on https://github.com/visavi/codeception-phpixie/ .

An obvious thing which is missing is Connector class.
Example: https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/blob/2.4.5/src/Codeception/Lib/Connector/Guzzle6.php#L183-L217

Connector class must extend BrowserKit\Client class (unless your framework is based on Symfony Http component, in that case look at the code of Symfony module and connector).
and implement doRequest method, which transforms BrowserKit\Request object to an object expected by your framework, invokes framework code and transforms framework response to BrowserKit\Response.

The middle part of doRequest method must be based on the code that you put to index.php of your site.

Ask questions in comments.

Comment: I create a connector, but before the doRequest method the query does not reach

[Error] Call to a member function isEmpty() on null 
/vendor/symfony/browser-kit/Client.php:593

Comment: Yes, it almost worked out, the tests work, but there’s a problem with the fact that I don’t know the phpixie framework very well and it’s not yet possible to correctly implement the request through the built-in methods
In the version that is now, I can only get the body of the answer
And the headers and response code has not yet been able to display
But from time to time I come back and work on it.

Comment: @Naktibalda maybe you could help me answering a similar question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/65393662/8307814