# How to run Codeception functional tests against a custom frameworkless web application? (that implements PSR-15 RequestHandlerInterface)

Tags: codeception

Assume the following simple web app:

```php
<?php
// src/App/App.php

namespace Practice\Sources\App;

use Closure;
use Laminas\Diactoros\ServerRequestFactory;
use Laminas\HttpHandlerRunner\Emitter\SapiEmitter;
use Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseFactoryInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use Psr\Http\Server\RequestHandlerInterface;

class App implements RequestHandlerInterface
{
    private Closure $requestProvider;
    private ResponseFactoryInterface $responseFactory;
    private SapiEmitter $responseEmitter;

    public function __construct(ResponseFactoryInterface $responseFactory)
    {
        $this->requestProvider = fn() => ServerRequestFactory::fromGlobals();
        $this->responseFactory = $responseFactory;
        $this->responseEmitter = new SapiEmitter();
    }

    public function run(): void
    {
        $request = ($this->requestProvider)();
        $response = $this->handle($request);
        $this->responseEmitter->emit($response);
    }

    public function handle(RequestInterface $request): ResponseInterface
    {
        $response = $this->responseFactory->createResponse();
        $response->getBody()->write('hello world');
        return $response;
    }
}
```

One can easily run it by placing the following code in their web front-controller (e.g. `public_html/index.php`):

```php
<?php
// web-root/front-controller.php

use Laminas\Diactoros\ResponseFactory;
use Practice\Sources\App\App;

require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

$responseFactory = new ResponseFactory();
$app = new App($responseFactory);
$app->run();
```

Now, I'd like to run Codeception feature tests against it, written in Gherkin. Consider the following simple test:

```
# tests/Feature/run.feature
# (also symlink'ed from tests/Codeception/tests/acceptance/ )

Feature: run app

  Scenario: I run the app
    When I am on page '/'
    Then I see 'hello world'
```

To run acceptance tests against it, I have to provide my steps implementation. I'll reuse standard steps for that, provided by the Codeception:

```php
<?php
// tests/Codeception/tests/_support/FeatureTester.php

namespace Practice\Tests\Codeception;

use Codeception\Actor;

abstract class FeatureTester extends Actor
{
//    use _generated\AcceptanceTesterActions;
//    use _generated\FunctionalTesterActions;

    /**
     * @When /^I am on page \'([^\']*)\'$/
     */
    public function iAmOnPage($page)
    {
        $this->amOnPage($page);
    }

    /**
     * @Then /^I see \'([^\']*)\'$/
     */
    public function iSee($what)
    {
        $this->see($what);
    }
}
```

```php
<?php
// tests/Codeception/tests/_support/AcceptanceTester.php

namespace Practice\Tests\Codeception;

class AcceptanceTester extends FeatureTester
{
    use _generated\AcceptanceTesterActions;
}
```

```yaml
# tests/Codeception/codeception.yml

namespace: Practice\Tests\Codeception
paths:
    tests: tests
    output: tests/_output
    data: tests/_data
    support: tests/_support
    envs: tests/_envs
actor_suffix: Tester
extensions:
    enabled:
        - Codeception\Extension\RunFailed
```

```yaml
# tests/Codeception/tests/acceptance.suite.yml

actor: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - PhpBrowser:
            url: http://practice.local
gherkin:
    contexts:
        default:
            - \Practice\Tests\Codeception\AcceptanceTester
```

But now, I want to use same tests code to run these same tests as functional tests using Codeception. For this, I have to [enable the module](https://codeception.com/docs/04-FunctionalTests#Enabling-Framework-Modules) that implements these same steps in functional way. Which one do I use? Codeception provides several, but they're for 3rd party frameworks, e.g. Laravel, Yii2, Symphony etc. **What do I do for such a simple app that doesn't use any 3rd party framework?**

Here's what I've managed to do. I've created my own `\Codeception\Lib\InnerBrowser` implementation that inherits from `\Codeception\Module\PhpBrowser` provided by Codeception, in which I substitute the web client that Codeception uses (it uses Guzzle) with my own implementation (which also inherits from the Guzzle client) that doesn't perform any web requests but requests my app instead:

```yaml
# tests/Codeception/tests/functional.suite.yml

actor: FunctionalTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - \Practice\Tests\Codeception\Helper\CustomInnerBrowser:
            url: http://practice.local
gherkin:
    contexts:
        default:
            - \Practice\Tests\Codeception\FunctionalTester
```

```php
<?php
// tests/Codeception/tests/_support/FunctionalTester.php

namespace Practice\Tests\Codeception;

class FunctionalTester extends FeatureTester
{
    use _generated\FunctionalTesterActions;
}
```

In order for this to work, I have to make my app return Guzzle `Response`s (which implement PSR's `ResponseInterface` as well) - because PhpBrowser expects its web client to return *them* - which is why I had to make the `ResponseFactory` a constructor parameter to be able to substitute it in tests.

```php
<?php
// tests/Codeception/tests/_support/Helper/CustomInnerBrowser.php

namespace Practice\Tests\Codeception\Helper;

use Codeception\Module\PhpBrowser;
use Http\Factory\Guzzle\ResponseFactory;
use Practice\Sources\App\App;

class CustomInnerBrowser extends PhpBrowser
{
    private App $app;

    public function __construct(...$args)
    {
        parent::__construct(...$args);
        $responseFactory = new ResponseFactory();
        $this->app = new App($responseFactory);
    }

    public function _prepareSession(): void
    {
        parent::_prepareSession();
        $this->guzzle = new CustomInnerBrowserClient($this->guzzle->getConfig(), $this->app);
        $this->client->setClient($this->guzzle);
    }
}
```

```php
<?php
// tests/Codeception/tests/_support/Helper/CustomInnerBrowserClient.php

namespace Practice\Tests\Codeception\Helper;

use GuzzleHttp\Client as GuzzleClient;
use Practice\Sources\App\App;
use Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;

class CustomInnerBrowserClient extends GuzzleClient
{
    private App $app;

    public function __construct(array $config, App $app)
    {
        parent::__construct($config);
        $this->app = $app;
    }

    public function send(RequestInterface $request, array $options = []): ResponseInterface
    {
        return $this->app->handle($request);
    }
}
```

In such a configuration, everything seems to work fine.

**But** there's a problem. Notice the `App::handle()` signature:

```php
    public function handle(RequestInterface $request): ResponseInterface
```

- it differs from the one that it implements, which is declared in `RequestHandlerInterface`:

```php
    public function handle(ServerRequestInterface $request): ResponseInterface;
```

Technically, it's completely legal because it doesn't break the [parameter contravariance](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.variance.php#language.oop5.variance.contravariance) required by the Liskov Substitution Principle.
The problem that I've faced is that `PhpBrowser` assumes that it sends a (client-side) `RequestInterface`s (over the network) but *my* app requires a (server-side) `ServerRequestInterface` instead, to be able to access parameters that are set on the server side such as `ServerRequestInterface::getParsedBody()`, session etc.

How do I workaround this? Framework modules provided by Codeception already do this somehow... And BTW, **haven't Codeception** (or someone else) **provided yet an easy way to run functional tests against custom code?**

Here's `composer.json` BTW:

```json
{
  "require": {
    "php": "~7.4",
    "laminas/laminas-diactoros": "^2.5",
    "laminas/laminas-httphandlerrunner": "^1.3"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "codeception/codeception": "^4.1",
    "codeception/module-phpbrowser": "^1.0.0",
    "http-interop/http-factory-guzzle": "^1.0"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Practice\\Sources\\": "src"
    }
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Practice\\Tests\\Unit\\": "tests/Unit/",
      "Practice\\Tests\\Support\\": "tests/Support/",
      "Practice\\Tests\\Codeception\\": "tests/Codeception/tests/_support/",
      "Practice\\Tests\\Codeception\\_generated\\": "tests/Codeception/tests/_support/_generated/",
      "Practice\\Tests\\Codeception\\Helper\\": "tests/Codeception/tests/_support/Helper/"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test-feature": "codecept run --config tests/Codeception/codeception.yml"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using codeception/module-laminas ? 
https://github.com/Codeception/module-laminas/

Comment: @Naktibalda no I haven't. Is is relevant at all? Looks like it tries to initiate some 3rd party application inside: https://github.com/Codeception/module-laminas/blob/c9f65ce6037ecefe03378adfc2dbd1e5e80e3063/src/Codeception/Lib/Connector/Laminas.php#L180 - while my app doesn't use any framework...

Comment: @Naktibalda why at all it is made so complicated? as i understand, the framework module must do 2 things: 1. convert framework-specific steps to an http request to be sent over the network. 2. convert the http request to a framework-specific result that may be used inside the test. additionally, to run the same code via functional tests, there must be a function that imitates the sending of the http request, that doesn't actually send it but instead it populates internal php structures such as $GLOBALS array in the same way it is populated by the php itself when it receives such a request.

Comment: @Naktibalda hence my question: why there is no such a basic module that imitates the http request sending and receiving and that can be used by all other framework-specific modules to run their steps in memory instead of sending them over network? or does such base module exist and i can inherit from it?

Comment: In fact we have such thing at https://github.com/Codeception/util-universalframework but it is only used to run some tests of Codeception itself.

Comment: @Naktibalda when i try to use it, my app cannot send headers because they're already sent - php doesn't allow subsequent request handling in the same process. that's why it's necessary to use the requestHanlderInterface instead - it allows to handle many requests in the same process without sending any headers. but the problem is that universalFramework internally uses BrowserKit\Request and i haven't found a way to convert it to psr request. i know symfony has a psr bridge, but it works with HttpFoundation\Request, not browserKit one... is there really no way to run functional tests this way?

Comment: That's why we have framework modules. And PSR-15 is not universal. There is only one official module using PSR (Mezzio). Some work on code reuse may be done when we have a second module using PSR requests (I've heard that Yii 3 will be using PSR)

Comment: There is so much code in your question. My advice is to stop trying to hijack PhpBrowser and write your own module for your frameworkless framework.

Comment: @Naktibalda that is, to write an adapter that translates `BrowserKit\Request`s to psr request and psr response to `BrowserKit\Response`s? :)

Comment: @Naktibalda btw as i understand, modern frameworks do support psr http messages. e.g symfony has its bridge to convert requests&response back and forth, so anyone who has a symfony app - may probably easily transform it into a psr requestHandler. also, laravel is based on symfony, therefore the above should be true for laravel as well. don't you think it'd be a good idea to enable anyone supporting psr to easily create a module for codeception with complete reuse of all existing actions like `amOnPage`, `see`, `click` etc? what do you think, interesting

Comment: @Naktibalda what about _my_ opinion - i even think that the php itself should've long time ago provide to its users(programmers) an api such as psr http messages instead of scattered functions & variables (as `$GLOBALS` and `header()`) - since such an interface would greatly ease the testing because with this interface, any web app becomes a php function `$response = handle($request)` which is very easy to test. donno why they haven't done that still...

Comment: There is no market for that :) You can implement it yourself and publish it on packagist.
Psr integration would have no benefits to Symfony and Laravel modules because they use HttpKernelBrowser instead of BrowserKit, so the integration is very simple.